# attributeList.push() is not working in cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The email(username) works but the given_name and family_name does not. I want to push this attributes so I can see it in cognito. I am using amazon-cognito-identity.js. Am I doing something wrong with the attributeList.push() method?

```
function registerButton() {
    var username = document.getElementById('personalemail').value;
    var given_name = document.getElementById('given_name').value;
    var family_name = document.getElementById('family_name').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('passwordInput').value;

    //starts gathering info from cognito
    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId : _config.cognito.userPoolId, 
        ClientId : _config.cognito.clientId 
    }

    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

    var attributeList = [];

    var dataEmail = {
        Name: 'email',
        value: username
    };
    var dataFirstName = {
        Name: 'given_name',
        value: given_name
    };
    var dataLastName = {
        Name: 'family_name',
        value: family_name
    };

    var attributeEmail = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
    var attributeFirstName = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataFirstName);
    var attributeLastName = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataLastName);   

    attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
    attributeList.push(attributeFirstName);
    attributeList.push(attributeLastName);

    userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }

        //location.replace("../register/subscriptionplans.html");
    });
}
```

Comment: haha silly me! I figured the error or more my typo. value has to be 'Value' instead of 'value'